# Проблема с установкой Scrapy в windows 7

Tags: python, windows, cmd, scrapy

**Моя цель:**
установить python\scrapy.

**Документация:**
Следую инструкции [вот этой](http://gis-lab.info/qa/scrapy.html#.D0.A3.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B0_Scrapy) документации.

**Что сделано:** Все пункты по документации, кроме установки самого Scrapy

**Проблема:**
При выполнении команды `pip install Scrapy` повисает с сообщением `collecting packages...`

Курсор мигает, но ничего не происходит
Также повисает в середине выполнения команда `pip list`

Подскажите пож-та, что это может быть и как это можно решить?

Comment: может попробовать 'python -m pip install -U pip'

Comment: Какая версия `Python` у вас? Вы настроили переменную среду для `pip`?

Answer (score 2):

Простите пожалуйста, но зачем Вы пользуетесь "вот той" документацией?
Есть же официальная http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/install.html
Там тоже описана установка на Windows. У меня при установке возникли проблемы только с lxml, что решилось скачиванием скомпилированной библиотеки отсюда: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

P.S. В той документации которую Вы привели предлагается установить easy_install, чтобы затем установить pip. Этого совсем не нужно было делать, так как на данный момент pip устанавливается вместе с Питоном.
Может быть, в результате Ваших действий возник какой-то конфликт версий. Попробуйте действительно обновить pip, как Вам посоветовали в комментарии, а если не выйдет, то снести всё и поставить заново, пользуясь официальной документацией.